# Show that the $G$-action on $R$ induces a $G$-action on $R/I$ defined by ${}^g \pi(r) = \pi({}^gr).$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, group-actions, quotient-spaces, automorphism-group

Here is the question that I want to answer part(d) in it:

Let $R$ be a ring and $I \subset R$ a two-sided ideal, with quotient homomorphism $\pi : R \rightarrow R/I.$ Let $\operatorname{End_{I}(R)}$ be the set of $\varphi \in \operatorname{End(R)}$ such that $\varphi(I) \subset I,$ and let $\operatorname{Aut_{I}(R)} = \operatorname{End_{I}(R) \cap Aut(R)}.$

$(a)$ Given $\varphi \in \operatorname{End_{I}(R)},$ show that there exists $\bar{\varphi} \in \operatorname{End(R/I)}$ such that $\bar{\varphi} \pi = \pi \varphi.$

$(b)$ Given $\varphi, \psi \in \operatorname{End_{I}(R)},$ show that $\overline{\varphi \psi} = \bar{\varphi} \bar{\psi}.$

$(c)$ Given $\varphi \in \operatorname{Aut_{I}(R)},$ show that $\varphi(I) = I$ and $\bar{\varphi} \in \operatorname{Aut(R/I)}.$\ Hint: Use part $(b).$

$(d)$ Let $G$ be a group which acts on $R$ by ring automorphisms and restricts to $I.$ Show that the $G-$action on $R$ induces a  $G-$action on $R/I$ defined by ${}^g \pi(r) = \pi({}^gr).$

**My question is:**

If I managed to prove parts (a), (b) and (c), could anyone give me a hint on how to prove (d)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that after a) b) and c) have been checked part d) is just an obvious rephrasing of them.

Just convince yourself that to have a group $G$ acting on $R$ by automorphisms amounts to have a group homomorphism $G\rightarrow{\rm Aut}(R)$ and then that given that the image lands in ${\rm Aut}_I(R)$ the induced map
$$
G\rightarrow{\rm Aut}(R/I),\qquad g\mapsto\bar\phi_g
$$
is again an homomorphism.

Comment: So I have to prove only that the given equation is an action and that it is a ring homomorphism? or I have to do what ? .... it is not clear to me what should I prove ..... also what are the ring automorphisms that $G$ acts on $R$ by?

Comment: @Confusion A group action of $G$ on $R$ means that for each $g\in G$ you have a map $\phi_g:R\rightarrow R$, $\phi_g(r)=gr$ satisfying the standard axioms of an action. As I said, convince yourself that if each map $\phi_g$ is an automorphism of $R$ then the association $g\to\phi_g$ is actually a group automorphism $G\rightarrow{\rm Aut}(R)$. Then follow the hint.

Comment: So I have to prove that $g\mapsto\bar\phi_g$ is a ring homomorphism?

Comment: So what is the relation between $\bar{\varphi_{g}}$ and the action given to us in the question? (defined by ${}^g \pi(r) = \pi({}^gr).$) how can I use it in the solution?

Comment: Sorry I understood that I should prove that it is a group homomorphism and not a ring homomorphism.